# What are the ozonolysis products of phenanthrene?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

What is / are the product(s) of ozonolysis of phenanthrene?

[image]

I am not sure I understand how to proceed. Which of the $\ce{C=C}$ double bonds is most susceptible to this type of reaction?

I am confused given the resonance and aromatic character of the compound which doesn't make me feel comfortable doing ozonolysis the usual way.

Comment: In anthracene (*an isomer* of your compound), the central ring is less aromatic (and susceptible e.g., to the Diels-Alder reaction) than the two outer ones.  Similar here, in phenanthrene, the double bond at position 9,10 is *easier* attacked by ozonolysis, than the other positions (relatively speaking).  So start from there.  You might infer from other resources as well, e.g. [OrganicSynthesis](http://www.orgsyn.org/demo.aspx?prep=CV5P0489), too. And it is *much* easier to keep track of the number of electrons with explicit dashes for single and double bonds, than with Thiele rings.

Comment: @Ashish In case of anthracene, [Clar's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polycyclic_aromatic_hydrocarbon#Bonding_and_aromaticity) is helpful.  On occasion, Wikipedia sub-section's tagged "chemistry" ([example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phenanthrene#Chemistry)) note *general* pattern.  An identification of these may be helped by the [structure explorer](https://www.cheminfo.org/wikipedia/), too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Phenanthrene reacts quickly with one mole of ozone at the 9,10-double bond according to this paper [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/264376421_The_ozonolysis_of_phenanthrene) and the OrgSyn procedure [here](http://orgsyn.org/demo.aspx?prep=CV5P0493) referred to above by @Buttonwood. In chloroform a polymeric mono-ozonide is obtained. In MeOH the reaction takes a different course resulting in the formation of a cyclic methoxy-hydroxy-peroxide and a cyclic dimethoxy-peroxide. Reductive work up (Zn/AcOH or Me2S) of these products gives the di-aldehyde.